# What happens to my existing visa if I get another visa from the same country?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, long-stay-visas, visa-cancellation

I am holding a C type Schengen visa received from Italy, valid from August 2017 to February 2018. On November 2017, I received another visa from Italy, this time D type National visa (not Schengen); it's for work purposes and it is valid for 1 year. Did my C type visa lose its validity after the issue of the National visa?

Comment: I presume they did not cancel the C visa by writing or stamping on it.  My question to you is why do you want to know?  The C visa expires before the D visa, so you derive no benefit from the C visa.

Comment: No they didn't do anything on it, no stamp or no indication about cancelling it. I would like to know because according to the Italian law before receiving "permesso di soggiorno" I am not allowed to move around in Schengen zone with the D visa as it is my first application for it.

Comment: http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722 It's written in the website of the state police

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter.

Your D visa gives you extended rights to stay in Italy and has for all practical purposes the same validity as a C visa in all other Schengen countries.

Comment: Unfortunately not. As I mentioned on my reply to @phoog 's comment, the italian law doesn't let the first-time applicants to go around schengen zone even with the receipt issued by the Italian post office after the application for "permesso di soggiorno". So C type visa would make the difference at this point when I go some other country in schengen zone. But i can't really confirm if it's still valid or not. Some resources say after the second visa was issued, the first one loses its validity; some say it is still valid.

Comment: @cleo456 The web page you are lnking to states correctly, that you are not allowed to enter other Schengen states *only* holding an Italian receipt for your residence permit application. It does not say that applying for a residence permit invalidates your D visa, with which you (independent of Italian law) is entitled to enter other Schengen states as if you had a C visa.

Comment: Applying for a residence permit doesn't invalidate my D visa, yes that's right. D visa itself is the one that lets me stay in Italy for 1 year, so in this time period I can do the procedures to get the residence card.

Comment: But i don't know whether the issuance of D visa caused my C visa to get invalidated (because both are issued by Italy). And if the C visa is invalid, it means I am not able to travel to other schengen countries. I may even need to apply for a schengen visa from another country in order to be able to move around schengen zone.

Comment: @cleo456 you can go to other Schengen countries with the D visa.  Nothing on the page you linked to contradicts that.

Comment: @phoog the web site says: The same facilitated procedure is granted to foreigners who have submitted their application for their first residence permits for employment, self-employment, or family reunification, provided that: ... - they do not transit through other Schengen countries, as this **is not allowed**.

Comment: @phoog so i still need to figure out if C visa is still valid. i tried to ask embassies but either they don't know or they don't pick up.

Comment: @cleo456 I think you need to find out why it's not allowed.  If it's not allowed because of the pending residence permit application, then having a C visa won't help.  If it's not allowed because they assume that you lack a valid D visa, then the assumption is false and you can travel elsewhere in Schengen, but the C visa still doesn't help. In other words, do they imagine it's not allowed because of Italian law or because of EU law?

Comment: @phoog Because of the Italian law, as far as I know. With the pending application, they don't let the applicant go around. Though, I don't understand how Italian law can bypass EU law.. But nothing mentioned about the case of having another visa. Anyway, thanks for all your replies, I will try to reach to the officials, and will post here if i can manage to get any proper answer.

Comment: @cleo456 Italian law is not bypassing EU law here.  If Italian law requires you to remain in Italy for your pending application to remain valid, for example, then that doesn't have any bearing on whether you have authorization to enter another Schengen country (or indeed any other country whatsoever).

Comment: @phoog Alright, thank you for all your help and time, i appreaciate that.